# How to find intersection of two sentences and include substrings

Tags: python, set, python-itertools, intersection

I am comparing sentences with jaccard similarity in Python.

However, I have a question for the intersection function:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
item1='She went to a restaurant on Oxford Street'.split(' ')
item2='She went to an Italian restaurant on Oxf. Street'.split(' ')

set.intersection(*[set(item1), set(item2)])
```

Result :

`{'She', 'Street', 'on', 'restaurant', 'to', 'went'}`

It only calculates intersection for strings that are completely identical, is there a way to include the word *Oxf* also, since it is short for *Oxford*? I.e., if a substring exists in the other set it should be included in the  intersection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pprint import pprint

def jaccard_similarity(str1, str2,
        exclude_words=set(["a", "an", "at", "in", "on", "is", "of", "with", "from", "to", "went"])):

    # Remove all periods "." to reduce later computation (num alias comparisons).
    x,y = [set(v.replace(".", "").split(" ")) - exclude_words for v in (str1, str2)]

    all_words = x | y
    word_aliases = dict()
    min_alias_length = 3

    for word in all_words:
        aliases = set([word[:i] for i in range(min_alias_length, len(word))])
        if aliases:
            word_aliases[word] = aliases

    print("Word aliases:")
    pprint(word_aliases)

    insert_aliases_for_words = {}
    for word, aliases in word_aliases.items():
        for words in (x, y):
            aliases_in_words = aliases & words
            if aliases_in_words:
                # Remove all aliases and replace with single "original" word.
                words -= aliases_in_words
                words.add(word)

    print("Unaliased word sets:")
    print(x)
    print(y)

    intersection = x & y

    print("Intersection:")
    print(intersection)

    intersection_cardinality = len(intersection)
    union_cardinality = len(x|y)
    return intersection_cardinality/float(union_cardinality)


import itertools
item1 = 'She went to a restaurant on Oxford Street'
item2 = 'She went to an Italian restaurant on Oxf. Street'

result = jaccard_similarity(item1, item2)
print(result)
```

Output:

```py
Word aliases:
{'Italian': {'Italia', 'Ital', 'Itali', 'Ita'},
 'Oxford': {'Oxfo', 'Oxf', 'Oxfor'},
 'Street': {'Stree', 'Stre', 'Str'},
 'restaurant': {'res',
                'rest',
                'resta',
                'restau',
                'restaur',
                'restaura',
                'restauran'}}
Unaliased word sets:
{'Oxford', 'Street', 'restaurant', 'She'}
{'She', 'restaurant', 'Oxford', 'Italian', 'Street'}
Intersection:
{'Oxford', 'She', 'restaurant', 'Street'}
0.8
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help. However, 'Oxf.' was just one example. I want to generalize this so that all shorter words can be matched with similar longer words.

Comment: The time complexity goes up if you generalise the solution, and becomes O(n^2) instead of O(n). Define "similar" - you mean every single substring abbreviation? Must all those end in a dot? It's easy enough to extend my solution yourself, you'd generate `word_aliases` in the function instead of hardcoding its value.

Comment: Thanks. The words doesn't necessary end in i a dot. There are too many possible combinations to not generalise.

Comment: Understood. Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution is you want your intersection to gather all words if one begin with the other (which will create problems in your case with words that are not really acronyms). It might be useful to someone

```
[x for x in set(item1) if any(x.startswith(u) or u.startswith(x) for u in set(item2))]
```